# SSRS sub reports and main report dynamically set size for main report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a report with 4 sub reports. The page size of the main report is 8.5 by 11 inches, but there is one sub-report which should be 11 by 8.5. At the moment when I export this it is extremely wonky. I do have a break between each report. Is there any way I can dynamically set the page orientation so that for that 1 report it would print 11 by 8.5 which the rest are exported as 8.5 by 11.

Answer (score 0):

Go to  Report>Report Properties and change the paper orientation to landscape  on the report that you want printed landscape.
[image]

Comment: Thanks...but that is not what I am asking. Those properties are already set. Within the main report I have the width and height set as 8.5 by 11. but one of the subreport has 11 by 8.5 size. When I export this to pdf, one of the report doesn't display properly So essentially within the export to pdf, I need to somehow change the size dynamically from 8.5  by 11 to 11 by 8.5.

Comment: Is the Sub report set to landscape?

Comment: Yes, and the main report is set to Portrait. It seems this is how it is.